# How to draw tan(x) without pgfplot?

Tags: tikz-pgf, plot

I want to know why output of the following MWE is ugly? i.e. `yrange=-3:3` has no effect!!

```
\documentclass[12pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}[domain=-4:4] 
    \draw[very thin,color=gray] (-0.4,-4) grid (4,4); 
    \draw[->] (-4.2,0) -- (4.2,0) node[right] {$x$}; 
    \draw[->] (0,-4.2) -- (0,4.2) node[above] {$y$};
    \draw[domain=-2*pi:2*pi, color=blue, samples=100, yrange=-3:3] plot[yrange=-3:3] (\x,{tan(\x r)}) node[right] {$f(x) = \tan x$}; 
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: This mean that `range` isn't like `clip`?

Comment: can you explain where is its effect exactly?

Comment: I think my above comment is not really to the point. `yrange` only has an effect if you plot the function with `gnuplot`. That is, you need the syntax `plot plot[id=tan-example] function{tan(x)}`.

Comment: You can add `\clip (-4,-3) rectangle (4,3);` after the grid and labels are done.

Comment: I know this and sorry for my question title. I want to know why `yrange=-3:3` or `range=-3:3` has no effect