# Tikz wrong calculation draw exponential function

Tags: tikz-pgf, calculations, tikz-graphs

Thanks for your help in advance:)

I have a problem with tikz calculating/printing the values of my function wrong.

The function is `f(x) = (ax³+bx²+cx)*e^(dx)` with `a=-3.01718 b=11.8804 c=0.753323 d=-0.790569`

The tikz graph looks very good from `x=0 to x=11.2`

**The graph gets wrong from `x > 11.4`**

You can compare the tikz graph to the graph from geogebra.

[image]

[image]

This is the code:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,11pt]{scrartcl}
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}%[scale=0.5]
\draw[thin,color=gray,xstep=1,ystep=1, solid] (0,-3) grid (13,7);
\draw[->,line width=0.8mm] (0,0) -- (13,0);
\draw[->,line width=0.8mm] (0,-3) -- (0,7);
\foreach \x/\xtext in {1/1, 2/2, 3/3, 4/4, 5/5, 6/6, 7/7, 8/8, 9/9, 10/10, 11/11, 12/12}
\draw[shift={(\x,0)}] (0pt,2pt) -- (0pt,-2pt) node[below] {$\xtext$};
\foreach \y/\ytext in {-2/-2, -1/-1, 0/0, 1/1, 2/2, 3/3, 4/4, 5/5, 6/6}
\draw[shift={(0,\y)}] (2pt,0pt) -- (-2pt,0pt) node[left] {$\ytext$};

\draw[line width=0.4mm, domain=0:12.8,smooth,variable=\x,black] plot ({\x},{((-3.017180* 
(\x)^3+11.88040*(\x)^2+0.753323*(\x))*e^(-0.790569*(\x))) });
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

**Thanks for your help!**

Comment: [Related](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/525885/108724)

Answer (score 15, accepted):

This is caused by how the pgf math function `exp` is implemented. A simplified example:

```tex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgfmath, pgffor}

\begin{document}
\foreach \i in {8.9, 9.0, 9.1} {
  \pgfmathparse{exp(-\i)}exp(-\i) = \pgfmathresult\par
}
\end{document}
```

The output is

```
exp(-8.9) = 0.00012
exp(-9.0) = 0.00012
exp(-9.1) = 0.00002  % <<< see the jump from 1.2e-4 to 2e-5
```

The relation between OP's example and mine is that, when `x ~= 11.384`, `-0.790569*(\x)` is near `-9`, so `e^x` becomes `e^{-9}`.

The [current implementation of `exp(x)`](https://github.com/pgf-tikz/pgf/blob/23ed8881b6710a3b687a68c1aa2c91a21410f6e5/tex/generic/pgf/math/pgfmathfunctions.basic.code.tex#L530-L558) simply returns `1/65536 ~= 0.00002` when `x < -9` (introduced by [commit `29a3525e6f5f`](https://github.com/pgf-tikz/pgf/commit/29a3525e6f5fb7acdf4ab02ae150bb651032bfa7) in 2008, from `pgf` 2.10), which causes the jumping value near `-9`.

Using a smaller jumping point instead of `-9` will trigger error `dimension too large` more often, hence is not a neat solution. For example, with `-10`, plotting OP's function will raise `dimension too large` near `x = 12.3`.

Using some floating-point calculation utility is better. The latest code base of `tikz-pgf` has introduced a new key `/pgf/fpu/install only={<math function list>}` which can be used to locally switch implementations of specific math functions to their `fpu` version.

The following example makes use of `install only` key, and will generate the same output as in [daleif's answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/563066). I guess `pgfplots` uses similar tricks to perform floating-point calculations when plotting.

```tex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{fpu}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}[declare function={
    f(\x) = (-3.017180*(\x)^3+11.88040*(\x)^2+0.753323*(\x))*e^(-0.790569*(\x));
  }]
  \draw[thin,color=gray]
    (0,-3) grid (13,7);
  \draw[->,line width=0.8mm]
    (0,0) -- (13,0)
    (0,-3) -- (0,7);
  \foreach \x in {1, 2, ..., 12}
    \draw[shift={(\x,0)}] (0pt,2pt) -- (0pt,-2pt) node[below] {$\x$};
  \foreach \y in {-2, -1, ..., 6}
    \draw[shift={(0,\y)}] (2pt,0pt) -- (-2pt,0pt) node[left] {$\y$};
  
  % use "/pgf/fpu/install only={exp}"
  \draw[line width=0.4mm, domain=0:12.8, smooth, /pgf/fpu/install only={exp}]
    plot (\x, {f(\x)});
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

#### Other choices

See `pgfmanual`, v3.1.5b,

- sec. 22.4 *Plotting Points Read From an External File* and
- sec. 22.6 *Plotting a Function Using Gnuplot*.

Comment: Thank you very much! Now i got a better understanding of whats causing the issue.

Comment: Next question/problem is, that the use of "/pgf/fpu/install only={exp}" doesnt work for me. I get the error "/pgf/fpu/install only={exp}"
I use texlive-pgf 3.1.5 (complete: 2020.176.3.1.5bsvn54512-41.2 on openSUSE tumbleweed)

Comment: @schreibelehmann Try https://github.com/pgf-tikz/pgf, the official repo. I've tested, that manually applying [commit `494bd677709b`](https://github.com/pgf-tikz/pgf/commit/494bd677709b9f2eb938d96eeb0c2ad29ae37aa3) works.

Comment: - Thanks for the clarification. I'm not good at programming and github stuff, thatswhy i just copied manually the addition lines from the patch you mentioned into my "/usr/share/texmf/tex/generic/pgf/libraries/pgflibraryfpu.code.tex" file. It works! Thanks alot!
When there is a texlive pfg-package update, shall i undo the manually changes? (Info: i have a safe-copy of the old file)

Comment: @schreibelehmann I guess the change will just be overwritten when updating.

Answer (score 12):

No idea why this particular plot looks like this, but I would never plot a function by hand like this. I'd use `pgfplots` where it looks like this

```
\documentclass[a4paper,11pt,border=10pt,]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz,pgfplots}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}%[scale=0.5]
\begin{axis}[
  width=13cm,
  ymin=-2.1,
  ymax=5.5,
  domain=0:12.8,
  no marks,
  axis x line=center,
  axis y line=center,
  ]

  \addplot[smooth] {((-3.017180*(\x)^3+11.88040*(\x)^2+0.753323*(\x))*e^(-0.790569*(\x)))};
  
\end{axis}

\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

(`pgfplots` has a massive amount of configuration options)

And the result is:

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much for your suggestion. I'm still learning how to use the \begin[axis] and \addplot yet. Thatswhy i did it the way postet earlier :)